# Trouble creating my binary tree data structure [Python]

Tags: python

This is what I have so far. I am rather confused, what am I missing here? Is it standard to do Node.left = Node(5)? I think confusing. Should I have a addLeft function in the Tree class that does that for me? Little confused on standard tree implementation.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None


t = Tree()
t.root = (Node(3))


print t.root.val
```

Comment: A common misunderstanding is that a Tree and a Node are different.  They are the same.  You don't need the Tree class at all.

Comment: I know but I rather a tree class to hold the root of the tree. I prefer two classes, if thats possible.

Comment: Actually you don't need such a function. You should just be able to add a node but where the node actually lands should be determined internally based on the properties every binary tree has. `self.right` and `self.left` should not be entered manually by the user of your tree. I've seen many implementations that don't do that and I find those pretty bothering. A tree (as well as any other data structure) should externally offer only the functionality that the user has to be able to use. The rest - all internal stuff (especially re-balancing the tree).

Comment: @GarrettR Yes and no. The `Tree` class is not necessary however in terms of semantics I find that for example `tree.search(...)` is much more appropriate than `node.search(...)`. Same goes for `tree.insertNode(...)` etc.. Nodes are the internal structures of a tree. Actually based on the implementation a `Tree` class might be even necessary (implementation via linked list for example would suggest that there is a top level container (the root is NOT such a container since it may change after re-balancing the tree!) that stores the nodes in that list).